# How to reverse number in sass

Tags: css, sass, less

I have a sass class like this:

```
@for $column from 1 through $columns {
    .column-#{$column} {
        @extend %set-margin;
        flex: 100% / $column;
    }
}
```

and the result like this:

```
.column-1 {
    flex: 100%
}
.column-2 {...}
...
```

I want reverse the result like:

```
.column-12 {
    flex: 100%
}
.column-11 {...}
...
```

how to reverse the result ?

Comment: why you accepted the other answer which is a simple copy of mine? he edited his answer to repeat what I already made ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just switch around the two variables `1` and `$columns` and divide the 100% by the inverse:

```
$columns: 4;

@for $column from $columns through 1 {
    .column-#{$column} {
        @extend %set-margin;
        flex: 100% / ($columns - $column + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply like below:

```
$columns:12;

@for $column from 1 through $columns {
    .column-#{$column} {
        flex: 100% / ($columns - $column + 1);
    }
}
```